# Pendulum's velocity and kinetic energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, velocity

I have the following pendulum:
[image]

In this case, the kinetic energy has this formula:

[image]

As far as I know, the kinetic energy is:

$T = mv^2/2$

So it follows that in this case the velocity of the pendulum is:

v = $l\dot\theta$

Why is that? How is the velocity calculated?

Comment: Would it look more familiar if it was written in the form $v = r \omega$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mass of the pendulum is moving along a circular trajectory with radius $l$. The arc length, $s$, of an arc which subtends an angle $\theta$ is given by:

$$s=\theta l$$

Displacement and velocity are related by time derivative:

$$v=\frac{ds}{dt}=\dot{\theta} l$$

Answer (score 1):

If the pendulum could do a complete circle, the bob would have covered a distance of $2\pi\ell$ and in the process in would have gone through an angle of $2\pi$. In general, if you move through an angle $\theta$ you have covered a distance $\ell\theta$. The velocity is distance divided by time; if you move just a very small distance, we compute the instant velocity by taking the derivative, so $v=\frac{d}{dt}\ell\theta = \ell\dot\theta$

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following generalized coordinates:

$$\begin{cases}x = l.cos(\theta) \\ y = l.sin(\theta)\end{cases}$$

you easily find these time derivatives:

$$\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = -l.sin(\theta).\dot{\theta} \\
\dot{y} = l.cos(\theta).\dot{\theta}
\end{cases}$$

and because $v^2 = \dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2$ you find:

$$v^2 = l^2.sin^2(\theta).\dot{\theta^2} + l^2.cos^2(\theta).\dot{\theta^2} = l^2\dot{\theta^2}$$